# C - sizeof(*ptr) vs sizeof(ptr)

Tags: c, manejo-de-memoria

En el caso de que...

```
int *ptr;

ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
```

¿Qué diferencia hay entre `sizeof(*ptr)` y `sizeof(ptr)`?

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(*ptr)` te devolvera el tamaño del contenido de tu puntero osea el tamaño de un `int` que normalmente es 4

`sizeof(ptr)` te devolvera el tamaño de la **dirección en memoria** de ptr osea el tamaño de un `int*` que normalmente es 8

Segun tu arquitectura te dara un valor u otro

### Otro ejemplo

De igual forma si tu codigo fuese

```
char *ptr;
ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
```

`sizeof(*ptr)` te devolvera el tamaño de un `char` que es 1

`sizeof(ptr)` te devolvera el tamaño de la dirección en memora de un `char` que normalmente es 8

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Qué diferencia hay entre `sizeof(*ptr)` y `sizeof(ptr)`?

La diferencia es obvia:

1. `sizeof(*ptr)` es el tamaño de (size of) `*ptr`.
2. `sizeof(ptr)` es el tamaño de (size of) `ptr`.

En C, el tamaño de los datos se calcula en bytes, así que usar `sizeof` sobre un entero de 32 bits (que generalmente es `int`) devuelve el valor 4 (8 bits por byte).

En el ejemplo que has mostrado el dato `ptr` es de tipo *puntero a entero* (`int *`). El tamaño de un puntero cambia según la [arquitectura](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arquitectura_de_computadoras) en que trabajes, pudiendo ser 4 (32 bits) u 8 (64 bits). La particularidad de los punteros es que tienen siempre el mismo tamaño independientemente del tipo de dato al que apunten:

```
int *pint;
short *pshort;

if (sizeof(pint) == sizeof(pshort))
    printf("Eureka!\n");
```

El código anterior mostrará `Eureka!`. Sin embargo, tipos de datos diferentes pueden tener un tamaño diferente:

```
int *pint;
short *pshort;

if (sizeof(*pint) == sizeof(*pshort))
    printf("Eureka!\n");
```

El código anterior no mostrará nada, ya que al usar el operador de des-referencia (el `*` unario) pediremos el tamaño de (size of) el **contenido** del puntero, no el tamaño del puntero.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` es una función que te devuelve el tamaño en *bytes* del parámetro que le pases.

En tu caso, debes tener en cuenta, que un puntero guarda es una *dirección de memoria*, y el tamaño de esta dirección cambia según tu arquitectura.

En un procesador *normal* de un bus de 32 bits, el tamaño de una dirección de memoria va a ser de 32 bits o 4 Bytes ya que por su bus de datos solo puede redireccionar esa cantidad de memoria, por eso a los procesadores de 32 bits solo se le puede asignar una RAM 4GB(más o menos), en un procesador de un bus de 64 bits, la dirección de memoria va a tener un tamaño de 64 bits o 8 Bytes.

```
char *ptr; 
size_t len = sizeof(ptr);
```

si haces eso he imprimes la variable `len`, vas a obtener o un **4** o un **8**, dependiendo de tu arquitectura y *sin importar* que tipo de dato sea, porque ahí se consulta es el tamaño del puntero(dirección de memoria) no del tipo de dato en es si.

```
char *ptr1;
int  *ptr2;

size_t len1 = sizeof(ptr1);
size_t len2 = sizeof(ptr2);
```

Por esa razón, sin importar que una variable sea de tipo `char` y la otra sea de tipo `int`, `len1` y `len2` obtendrán el mismo resultado.

Cuando pasas un puntero con el asterisco en frente o el operador de res-referencia, ya estas es accediendo a el dato al cual el esta apuntando, ahí si diferenciaría que tipo de dato es, los cuales poseen diferentes tamaños.

```
char *ptr1;
int  *ptr2;

size_t len1 = sizeof(*ptr1);
size_t len2 = sizeof(*ptr2);
```

En este ejemplo si habrá una diferencia, porque `ptr1` apunta es a un tipo de dato `char` el cual solo es de 1 Byte, y `ptr2` apunta a un tipo de dato `int` el cual es de 4 bytes.